# JGit does not pull the remote reset

Tags: jgit, git-reset

I am seeing a strange behaviour, I don't know if it is a bug or a feature.
From machine #1 I do `git reset --hard someCommit && git push -f`. The reset is then propagated to all machine (I can see the change by doing a `git pull` or `git log`from another machine).

From machine #2 that runs JGit I perform: `git.pull().call()` but the reset is not applied and the files on disk are not changed. Also `git.log().call()` does not point to the reverted commit.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) described, you likely need to *force* fetch on the other computers.

The return value of `PushCommand::call()` will tell you if and why the push did not succeed.

To force pull in JGit, follow this example:

```java
git.fetch()
  .setForce( true )
  .setRefSpec( new RefSpec( "refs/heads/someBranch:refs/remotes/origin/someBranch" ) )
  .call();
git.reset()
  .setMode( ResetType.HARD )
  .setRef( "someBranch" )
  .call();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `git.pull.call()` command is being rejected.  You executed the following commands:

```
git reset --hard someCommit
git push -f
```

The first one should completely reset the branch to `someCommit`.  The second one force pushes the reset branch to the remote, rewriting the history of the branch in the process.  The keyword here is `-f` which is short for `--force`.

Because you rewrote the history of this branch, other computers will no longer be able to do a simple `git pull` because the base of the branch has changed.  So I believe that your JGIT call to `git.pull().call()` is failing with an error.  To fix this, you need to "force" pull the branch on the other computers:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout someBranch
git reset --hard origin/someBranch
```